# Get Data From two Lists conditionally using LINQ Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, entity-framework

I have two Lists:

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities()) {

    var userInfoList = context.UsersInfoes.ToList();
    var membersList = context.Members.ToList();

}
```

These two list are represented on tables as below;

[image]

[image]

I want to be able to iterate through both lists **WHERE THE TEAMID is equal to '10'** and **add FKUserID and Name to a third list where FKUserID is matching in both tables**.

[image]

Is there anyway I can do this as efficiently as possible and **produce these results in the third list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [linq join clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause:) as follows:

```
var ThirdList = 
    from member in MembersList
    join userInfo in UserInfoList on member.FKUserID equals userInfo.FKUserID
    where member.TeamID == 12  // change 12 to the TeamID needed
    select new { TeamID = member.TeamID, FKUserID = member.FKUserID, Name = userInfo.Name};

foreach(var tlist in ThirdList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", tlist.TeamID, tlist.FKUserID, tlist.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
12 | 6 | kjh
12 | 7 | ghg
12 | 8 | dfi
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this LINQ but it should work.  You said you wanted TeamID = 10, but used 12 in your tables.  Obviously, just change the 12 to whatever you want the TeamID to be.

```
        var ThirdList = (from y in userInfoList join z in membersList on y.FKUserID equals z.FKUserID 
                         where z.TeamID == 12 
                         select new { 
                               TeamID = z.TeamID,
                               FKUserID = z.FKUserID,
                               Name = y.Name
                                    } ).ToList();
```